# Odoo v10 @onchange(stage_id) doesn't work with <field name="stage_id" widget="statusbar" clickable="True"/>

Tags: python, odoo, project, onchange

Odoo v10 @onchange(stage_id) doesn't work with stage_id widget field. When I added field simple field in form body it worked, but not with original:

```
<field name="stage_id" widget="statusbar" clickable="True"/>

class TaskExtension(models.Model):
    _name = 'project.task'
    _inherit = ['project.task']

    @api.model('stage_id', 'date_deadline')
    def _onchange_responsible(self):
        self.user_id = self.stage_id.responsible


    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users',string = 'Assigned To',computed = _onchange_responsible,store=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **If statusbar is clickable then onchange method won't call. It will directly call write method.**

So you need to deal with write method in that case.

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    res = super(class_name, self).write(vals)
    ### your logic
    return res
```

If you want to call onchange function then you can use **@api.onchange** decorator.

**@api.model** will be used while you want to call any methods without any objects (using model reference / blank recordset).

**@api.onchange** will be used to call function while one or more filed's value gets updated.

```
@api.onchange('field1', 'field2')
def function_name(self):
    # your logic here like:
```

Finally your method should looks like,

```
@api.onchange('stage_id')
def on_change_stage_id(self):
    self.user_id = self.stage_id.responsible
```

> In odoo onchange method field must me available(visible/invisible) in
>   the form view, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Waht's an issue ?

Comment: self.user_id doesn't change. I've tried to put print statement before, nothing gets printed to command line. It seems that function doesn't get called at all

Comment: It is visible. Orginal form from source has it.

Answer (score 3):

On change function should be written like this

```py
@api.onchange('stage_id')  # triggered fields
def on_change_stage_id(self):
    # your logic here like:
    if self.stage_id:
       self.user_id = self.stage_id.responsible
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. It's the only field, which doesn't work. It works with every field in onchange, but not the one I need...

Comment: but is the field value change or you need when you click on it to trigger this function

Comment: If the statusbar is clickable then onchange will not be called. It will call write method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<field name="state" widget="statusbar" options="{'fold_field': 'fold'}" clickable="True"/>
```